# Solr Installation problem: I can't get in to the admin page http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/admin

Tags: java, linux, search, full-text-search, solr

I followed the getting started guide in http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html. But I can't get in to the admin page. I have installed Solr in my remote server. And I try access the admin page via http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8983/solr/admin

Comment: what errors are you getting (in your browser, in the log files)? is the network connectivity ok?

Comment: Indeed, Mat. Try pinging or telnet to that ip and port. Can you access the admin page if you're 'on' the remote machine (remote desktop e.g.).

Comment: I cant get in the so I think http 404?

Comment: Is there a firewall running? Or a proxy only allowing ports 80 and 443? What happens if you connect to the remote server using ssh and start a browser (even text-based, `lynx` or `w3m` for example), pointing it to `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin` ?  If port 80 isn't in use yet, does it work with jetty listening at port 80 (change the port in `example/etc/jetty.xml`, search for "`jetty.port'". property)? - edit: sorry, haven't seen the other comments posted before...

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I managed th solve it myself. I just used the 3.1.0 version instead of 3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. In my case, the port was not accessible to the outside world. When I opened port 8983 I was able to access the Solr dashboard.